# Why is my mesh not smooth?

Tags: modeling

I am new to 3d modelling and blender and I am confused with why my mesh colour looks different to the one in DARRIN LILE's video.
[image]

This is mine, but it looks a bit metallic or something compared to his which looks smooth. Im not sure wats wrong.

[image]

Comment: Please make an effort to describe what you want as part of the title. Read: [What is the problem with posting an image (or link) and asking “How do I do this?”](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this)

Comment: He is using smooth shading.

Answer (score 3):

Your model is showing faces and edges, called Flat Shading, while the video shows a Smooth Shaded geometry.

Go to Object Mode, look in the Tool Panel on the 3D window (left hand panel, press T if hidden) and find the Shading buttons. Press Smooth.

It will now look like the video.